# Unable to call custom appender for Log4Net in .Net Core API

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, log4net, log4net-appender

Here is my code. 
I am using only Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore reference 
I am getting following exception in debug window. can you please guide me in setting up log4net config file.

```
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using XML element
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [Error].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ERROR",value=70000].
log4net: Loading Appender [AuditAppender] type: [Logger.Log4NetAuditAppender]
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [AuditAppender] of type [Logger.Log4NetAuditAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Logger.Log4NetAuditAppender' from assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [AuditAppender] not found.
```

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    { 
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); 
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config")); 
    }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
    { 

    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net(); 
    app.UseMvc(); 
    }
```

my log4.net config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <log4net debug="true"> 
    <root> 
    <level value="Error" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="AuditAppender" /> 
    </root> 
    <appender name="AuditAppender" type="Logger.Log4NetAuditAppender,Logger"> 
    </appender> 

    </log4net>
```

my custom appender

```
public class Log4NetAuditAppender : AppenderSkeleton 
    { 
    public Log4NetAuditAppender(){ 
    } 
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) 
    { 
    Console.WriteLine("coming inside"); 
    } 
    } 
    }
```

my controller

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")] 
    [ApiController] 
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase 
    {

    private ILogger<ValuesController> _logger; 
    public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger) { _logger = logger;}

    [HttpGet("{id}")] 
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id) 
    {
      _logger.LogInformation("test", null);
       return "value";
    }
```

Comment: Probably need to give the fully qualified assembly name of the custom appender, since it's currently looking in the log4net assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, 
After adding Assembly name after full class name in appender tag, it got resolved.

```
<appender name="AuditAppender" type="Logger.Log4NetAuditAppender,Logger">
```

Just replace ",Logger" with , and it should work.